MUi table sorting not working on nested array of filed called name
Please find live code example below link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ashok-reddy?file=muitable.tsx

Sorting was not working on name filed of nested array but it is only working for id field on MUI table.

Sorting was not working in MUI table:

as show in screenshot :
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/YjT3NIEx.png)

